# Photoshop "Export > Export As" or "Export > Save For Web" in size 600px + auto suffix in filename

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

When working with an image in Photoshop, I'd like to have a **simple keyboard shortcut**, like in [Photoshop shortcut for File, Save As, Format: PNG or JPG, Save, OK](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109939/photoshop-shortcut-for-file-save-as-format-png-or-jpg-save-ok), that automatically does:

- *Export > Export As* or *Export > Save For Web*
- Resize to biggest dimension = 600px (either width or height)
- Add suffix `_600.jpg` to filename

**How to do that?**

I'm not sure how to edit a recorded macro to do that (add the suffix and choose 600px for the biggest dimension).

Example: you open `myphoto.png`, you press `F6` and then you automatically get `myphoto_600.jpg`.

Comment: I had a similar query recently - I wouldn't hope to be able to tell you how to tweak that for your particular requirement, but just to link the two together for future searches… https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/photoshop-batch-save-two-files-from-one-source-specific-data-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the modified version of the script that @Tetsujin has mentioned. It'll save a 600px jpg (you can set the max size in the `targetSize` variable) to the folder of the active document with a `name_600.jpg`:

```
function main()
{
  var targetSize = 600;
  var fileName = activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, "");
  var width = activeDocument.width.as('px');
  var height = activeDocument.height.as('px');

  var filePath, scale, ratio;

  try
  {
    filePath = activeDocument.path;
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    alert('File was never saved, aborting');
    return false;
  }

  ratio = width / height;

  scale = ratio >= 1 ? targetSize / width : targetSize / height;

  saveForWeb(fileName + "_" + targetSize + ".jpg", filePath, 90, scale * 100);

  function saveForWeb(fileName, filePath, quality, scale)
  {
    function cTID(s)
    {
      return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    function sTID(s)
    {
      return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    var desc21 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('Op  '), cTID('SWOp'), cTID('OpSa'));
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('DIDr'), true);
    desc22.putPath(cTID('In  '), new File(filePath)); // file path
    desc22.putString(cTID('ovFN'), fileName); // file name
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('Fmt '), cTID('IRFm'), cTID('JPEG'));
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('Intr'), false);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('Qlty'), quality); // quality
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('QChS'), 0);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('QCUI'), 0);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('QChT'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('QChV'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('Optm'), true);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('Pass'), 1);
    desc22.putDouble(cTID('blur'), 0.000000);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('Mtt '), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('EICC'), false);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('MttR'), 255);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('MttG'), 255);
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('MttB'), 255);
    desc22.putUnitDouble(cTID('HScl'), cTID('#Pxl'), scale); // scale
    desc22.putUnitDouble(cTID('VScl'), cTID('#Pxl'), scale); // scale
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('SHTM'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('SImg'), true);
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('SWsl'), cTID('STsl'), cTID('SLAl'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('SWch'), cTID('STch'), cTID('CHsR'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('SWmd'), cTID('STmd'), cTID('MDCC'));
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohXH'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohIC'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohAA'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohQA'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohCA'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ohIZ'), true);
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('ohTC'), cTID('SToc'), cTID('OC03'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('ohAC'), cTID('SToc'), cTID('OC03'));
    desc22.putInteger(cTID('ohIn'), -1);
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('ohLE'), cTID('STle'), cTID('LE03'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('ohEn'), cTID('STen'), cTID('EN00'));
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('olCS'), false);
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olEC'), cTID('STst'), cTID('ST00'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olWH'), cTID('STwh'), cTID('WH01'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olSV'), cTID('STsp'), cTID('SP04'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olSH'), cTID('STsp'), cTID('SP04'));
    var list3 = new ActionList();
    var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc23.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC00'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc23);
    var desc24 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc24.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC19'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc24);
    var desc25 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc25.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC28'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc25);
    var desc26 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc26.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc26);
    var desc27 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc27.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc27);
    var desc28 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc28.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list3.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc28);
    desc22.putList(cTID('olNC'), list3);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('obIA'), false);
    desc22.putString(cTID('obIP'), "");
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('obCS'), cTID('STcs'), cTID('CS01'));
    var list4 = new ActionList();
    var desc29 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc29.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC01'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc29);
    var desc30 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc30.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC20'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc30);
    var desc31 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc31.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC02'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc31);
    var desc32 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc32.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC19'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc32);
    var desc33 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc33.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC06'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc33);
    var desc34 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc34.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc34);
    var desc35 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc35.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc35);
    var desc36 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc36.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC24'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc36);
    var desc37 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc37.putEnumerated(cTID('ncTp'), cTID('STnc'), cTID('NC22'));
    list4.putObject(cTID('SCnc'), desc37);
    desc22.putList(cTID('ovNC'), list4);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ovCM'), false);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ovCW'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ovCU'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ovSF'), true);
    desc22.putBoolean(cTID('ovCB'), true);
    desc22.putString(cTID('ovSN'), "images");
    desc21.putObject(cTID('Usng'), sTID('SaveForWeb'), desc22);
    executeAction(cTID('Expr'), desc21, DialogModes.NO);
  }

}
main();
```

You can save it as a `scriptname.jsx` file to `Photoshop Folder/Presets/Scripts/`, after restarting Photoshop you'll find it in `File > Scripts > scriptname`. You can then assign a shortcut to it from `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` menu.

Comment: @Basj you probably copied it wrong, all the brackets are in place. `cTID()` and `sTID()` are shortcuts for `charIDToTypeID()` and `stringIDToTypeID()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oops I didn't see the scrollbar :) What are these many similar lines `desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olEC'), cTID('STst'), cTID('ST00'));
    desc22.putEnumerated(cTID('olWH'), cTID('STwh'), cTID('WH01')); ...` for? Are such lines really required to just simply save to JPG?

Comment: @Basj please read the original answer to understand where this code comes from. You can save a JPG with one line of code, but it this will be Save As, not Save For Web: so this won't resize the result. You can rewrite this thing with shorter functions but it'll work differently and slower (clone document, resize it, save it, close the clone)

Comment: Thanks again! Very last thing: what language is it? It looks a bit like Javascript, but what does x mean in .jsx? Is it https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html?

Comment: @Basj basically those are _all_ options of Save for Web explicitly set. If you want, you can clean it and remove most of them from the function. This won't have any impact on performance or whatnot, you'll just waste some time

Comment: this is Extendscript. It's like Javascript and Actionscript together. React uses the same acronym so sometimes there is confusion. JSX is based on quite old JS standards: no `.filter()`, `.map()`, etc (though those can be added via polyfill)

Comment: You can find more information in PS JS references: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: @Basj ah, forgot the obvious: the most important is that it can talk with Adobe apps via DOM (and AM-code that's specific to Photoshop) and it has access to the file system.

Comment: Wow this seems like great scripting features!