# Directly save a jpg after cropping without jpeg option panel

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, save, crop, jpeg

I have a jpeg image in Adobe Photoshop.

If I only crop it, it cannot be saved directly (`Delete Cropped Pixels` checked). There was a jpeg option panel opened to let me choose quality, etc.

It is annoying when I want to crop images in batch. Also, the size is even three times larger than the original when I choose to save with the best quality.

How I can save the jpeg image directly, without this option panel?

Or what other App can I use to crop images in batch?

Cropping png doesn't have this problem in Photoshop though and I remember that in Photoshop CS5, it was also not a problem.

Comment: You can create an Action with specific SaveForWeb or SaveAs settings and use it for batching: manually or with Automate > Batch command. This way the settings window won’t appear

Comment: You can also set this action to preserve file names etc. I had a QA where I needed to learn how to do this. The answer is quite complex but you can just copy/paste & change the relevant parts. - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/photoshop-batch-save-two-files-from-one-source-specific-data-naming - This has been an absolute boon to my workflow ever since.

Answer (score 2):

When using the Crop Tool, be certain `Delete Cropped Pixels` **is checked** in the control bar across the top of the screen.

[image]

If cropped pixels are deleted you should be able to simply save the jpg.

**BE AWARE** JPG is a *lossy* format, which means... saving a jpg *as a jpg* reduces image quality in *all* instances.

If the `Delete Cropped Pixels` option is *unchecked* the layer gets unlocked and you introduce transparency, which is unsupported in the jpg format, causing the jpg options dialog to appear when saving.